# how to remove zero if hours less then 10 from d3.time.format("%I %p")

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am very new to d3.js. I am using `d3.time.format("%I %p")` which returns hours with a zero appended with single digit.

For example `new Date(1985,11,1,5,39,13)` returns `05`. How to make it return a single digit if hour is less than `10`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply write a minus sign before I:

```
d3.time.format("%-I %p");
```

Comment: Anyone knows how to get this: `9 p.m.` , instead of this: `9 PM` ?

Comment: @DanielGarcíaBaena Just change your [locale definition](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#timeFormatLocale). Look at "periods".